# What is the meaning of Winter Summer Bash favicon?

Tags: support, winter-bash, favicon, winter-bash-2022

As can be seen [here](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/), this is the favicon of Winter Summer Bash site:

[image: winter summer bash 2022 favicon]

What is the meaning behind choosing those colors, in that order? (I don't remember when SE started using this icon.)

Comment: Obviously it means: ikea watermelon.

Comment: Surrender to your swedish-dutch overgourds now.

Comment: The designers had a day off and Spolsky had a go at it ...

Comment: spring summer fall winter. pinkier summers than we get here though.

Comment: @philipxy they might have seen your comment, pink is now removed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I designed this favicon.

The top two colours are from the Summer Bash theme and the bottom two are from the Winter Bash theme. There is no other meaning but to fit the two colour palettes.

The favicon was updated just a few days after the countdown was live as we were preparing the site.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. But Why are the colors different every year?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars We choose different colors to fit the new illustrations.

Answer (score 5):

As I can see from my bookmarks, this favicon was already used last year, while the favicon in 2020 also followed this design theme already, but had slightly different colors:

[image]

so it seems to me just a way to point out graphically that it is holiday season and the Winter/Summer Bash is ON and no further specific meaning.

**edit:** the Winterbash 2022 favicon has changed in the meantime, following the same theme from the previous years, and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You are mistaken. These are obviously "scabby beach", and "duller ikea watermelon".

Comment: ikea has watermelons?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek well, the seeds, outer bit, and inner bits come separately.

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer the question I asked. 1) You don't give reasoning behind those specific colors, 2) Previous years have different colors in different order. My own best guess is that it's just random (machine generated) and we're wasting our time anyway, but that's only a guess. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: from my original answer: *so it seems to me just a way to point out graphically that it is holiday season and the Winter/Summer Bash is ON and no further specific meaning.*

Comment: Well only the one who made it, or gave the order, can tell for sure. Essentially the answer says "SE using four colorful bars as the favicon for several years, and it means it's holiday". While probably true in some way, I'm looking for explanation behind this and what each color means, if anything.